# How to solve this Java type safety warning?

Tags: java, generics, casting, struts2

```
Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.put("user", user);
```

This code generates a warning: *Type safety: The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type Map. References to generic type Map<K,V> should be parameterized*.

```
Map<String, Serializable> session = (Map<String, Serializable>)ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.put("user", user);
```

This code generates a warning: *Type safety: Unchecked cast from Map to Map<String,Serializable>*.

The **getSession** method belongs to Struts2 so I can't modify it. I would like to avoid using @SuppressWarnings because other warnings can be useful.

I guess all Struts2 users in the world faced the same problem... is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there's any other way but @SuppressWarnings("unchecked"). I believe you can put it just above the line in question, and it will only suppress that line.

Edit: you can also do `Map<?, ?> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();` but I'm not sure how willing you are to do that; you won't be able to put anything into the map that way (since the compiler can't check the type of what you're putting), only read from it.

Answer (score 7):

The safest, most efficient way to deal with this is probably:

```
Map<?, ?> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
```

and then type cast the objects retrieved from the session map.

The @SuppressWarnings approach will actually result in compiled code that is identical.  However the type cast will be implicit; i.e. it won't be easy to spot by looking at the source code.  And the @SuppressWarnings annotation could (hypothetically) suppress some *other* warning in the same code block that represents a real error; i.e. one that will result in one of the hidden typecasts, etc failing at runtime.

Other more expensive alternatives include:

- an entry by entry copy from the `Map<?, ?>` to a new `Map<String, Serializable>` instance casting the keys and values to `String` and `Serializable` respectively, or
- a generic method like the following that performs the typecast safely.

---

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <K,V> Map<K,V> castMap(Map<?, ?> map, Class<K> kClass, Class<V> vClass) {
    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        kClass.cast(entry.getKey());
        vClass.cast(entry.getValue());
    }
    return (Map<K,V>) map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Struts 2 (especially `XWork`) are you using? For me, your following code gives an error:

```
Map<String, Serializable> session = (Map<String, Serializable>)ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.put("user", user);

Cannot cast from Map<String,Object> to Map<String,Serializable>.
```

This, on the other hand, works and gives no warnings:

```
Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
```

Comment: I use 2.1.8.1 which is the latest version. Your suggestion gives this warning: Type safety: The expression of type Map needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<String,Object>

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext.html It seems that the 2.1.8.1 getSession should return a parameterized map. Are you sure it's properly installed and not using an older version previously installed?

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul: Something is different in our environments then since I don't get a warning. I would still check what XWork version you're using.

Comment: Indeed I actually had two versions installed and was mistakenly using an older one, sorry for the confusion, and thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It is requesting you to parameterize the value, if the value needs parameters then pass them.

For example

```
Map<Integer, Map> vCombinedCodeMap = new HashMap<>();
```

will give warning for "parameterized" `Map<Integer, Map>`.

so the correct format is the following:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> vCombinedCodeMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you do it like this:

```
Map<String, Serializable> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
```

Comment: It gives another warning: Type safety: The expression of type Map needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<String,Serializable>

Answer (score 0):

Cast as Following,

```
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> sessionMap) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    this.sessionMap = (SessionMap<String, Object>) sessionMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just write `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` at top of the `@GET` method, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class CustomHashMap<K, V> {

  private class Entry {
    private K key;
    private V value;

    public Entry(K key, V value) {
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
    }

  }

  private LinkedList<Entry>[] entries = new LinkedList[5]; // this line shows warning to check types
}
```